# Using transactions in Django when importing files

Tags: python, django

I'm building a Django app where the users will import an Excel/CSV file. Each row is fed through a form as explained [here](http://www.pydanny.com/core-concepts-django-modelforms.html) (Example 3 at the bottom).

For my importer, I first run through the entire file and I display any errors in a table. If there's no errors I display a summary of what will be imported. The user can than confirm and the file will be imported. The problem is, the rows depend on each other for validation (uniqueness constraints etc), so I have to save each row to the DB for the validation to work.

I've come up with the approach below, but I haven't used atomic transactions before and I'm worried about potential gotchas. I could be importing up to 10 000 rows.

Is the code below fine for what I want to achieve or are there better methods?

```
def import_from_csv(filename, preview):
    sid = transaction.savepoint()
    result = import_data(filename)
    if result.has_error or preview:
        transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
    else:
        transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
    return result
```

**Additional info:**

In my app have have two distict views. The first view is a preview view. In this case I call import_from_csv with preview set to True. That way the inserts will always be rolled back. It returns the results of what would have been imported. If there are no errors, I save the location of the file in a session variable. If the user clicks confirm, I call import_from_csv again, but this time preview is False. Since I already checked the file in the preview step, there shouldn't be any errors and the results will be committed. I know this could be optimized since I'm processing the file twice.

I'm using Django 1.9 and Postgres (on Heroku)

Comment: What version of Django are you using? If it's a modern version you should use `transaction.atomic` unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gotcha 1**

Inserting 10,000 rows isn't going to be very rapid no matter what the database is. You might just be able to squeeze it in before timeouts but you are taking a chance.

**Gotcha 2**

In a transaction, once an error has occurred that transaction cannot be used for further inserts untill you rollback. If the 2nd line in your CSV causes an error, you will find that nothing actually get's inserted.

*Based on your updated information:*

You would still have a hard time figuring out what records can be inserted and what cannot be. You might perhaps need `auto commit` in `import_data` which would slow things down even further.

**Gotcha 3**

The approach does not actually provide and opportunity for the user to confirm or reject the insert. The user action will be processed by a separate HTTP request. It will be different from the one that sent the CSV data. As a result by which time the user action is recieved this transaction is done and dusted and cannot be rolled back.

**Gotcha 4**

If earlier rows depends on latter rows (you said there maybe a relationship between rows) the insert will fail.

**Solution**

Use database bulk loading to populate a temporary table which is identical to the real thing *except for contraints*. You haven't specified what your database is. For example the way to bulk load in postgresql is with [COPY FROM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) and in mysql it's [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Add the constrains to the temporary table after the data is loaded. Do a join with the original table to identify which rows are duplicated. Ask the user whether to ignore or update duplicates. Then do a INSERT SELECT

*Response to additional information provided:*

If you are using a celery tasks you might not be dependent on COPY but it would still be better to do the initial import into a temporary table. That way you avoid the need to process the data twice. And it's really easy to figure out which lines in the CSV file lead to duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. 1. Good point, I'll move it to a Celery task 2. If there's an error, won't it roll back and nothing will be inserted? I want either all the records or none of the records to be inserted 3. I didn't explain it well enough, I've edit my question to give more info. Given the update, do you still think COPY FROM is the best approach? I'm quite new to Django and don't really want to drop down to raw sql unless I have to.

Comment: point 2: oops sorry my bad fixed and also updated in response to your question update

Comment: Can we create a temporary table in django on sqlite3 db?